# ASP.NET MVC razor view, post to a different model from the original model binding?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, model-binding

Well I have a group controller and view in the project, in which the model binding is GroupViewModel. But the group page is complex, and users will be able to make discussion topics. On this group view page, I have forms that allow users to post topics/replies. The model used for these forms can be TopicViewModel or ReplyViewModel, but the original model binding is only for GroupViewModel. It is declared at the beginning of the cshtml page:

```
@model MyProject.ViewModels.GroupBrowseViewModel
```

So I wonder, is it possible to have forms bind to different view model from the one declared at the top? If so, how to achieve this?

Comment: use partial views for the sections of the page that require binding to a different model.

Comment: thanks, the partial view idea works.

Comment: Well I have another question though. The issue is that I need to pass a parameter from the parent view to partial view, how is this possible? This value is the group ID, since topic will need to keep group ID as a foreign key value. I also worry that if this value is kept as hidden field on the post new topic form, users will be able to change it to something else through firebug or inspect element. What should I do in this case?

Answer (score 5):

Model binding really has nothing to do with the model used in your razor view.  At least not technically.

The first thing you have to understand is that there is no magic here.  This is straight HTTP posted values, and if you don't understand how HTTP posting works, I suggest you read up on it.  It's just a series of name/value pairs.

When you post, the routing framework looks at the selected action method, and the parameters that method takes, then it creates new instances of those parameters, and tries to match them up with similarly named values from the posted values.

So, in other words, there is no direct connection here between the model you use on the page, and the model used in the posted controller action.  It's all based on naming convention.  This naming convention is "helped" by the model you declare on the page, and the Html helpers create form fields with names that match up to model entries so that the model binder can figure these out more easily.

So, what this means is that in order to post to a different action, with a different model, all you need are fields in your form that have the names that the new model expects.

This can be done in a number of ways, from defining those fields manually, to using Partial view in which you pass an instance of the model you intend to post to as the model parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 partial views in the same view, and switch from the controller which one to show.

Or you can make a new ViewModel and this view model will contain references to both of your views, and in the view html based on your logic your can switch reading from any child ViewModel.